# Files required in parent component are not accessible to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on React project from a while, I just got a small idea, when we are requiring a file in Parent component like below

```js
var something = require('../../utils/properties.js');
```

why cant we access that in child component without requiring again, is there any way that we can do this or put all the requires in one file and access them across the project?

Comment: Parents and child *components* are not equivalent to parent or child *classes*. If you need to communicate between parent and child, use `props`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `something` as a prop to the child component. Read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html)